# How would I go about getting UPnP working on a Slackware server/firewall?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, slackware, upnp

I'm a long time fan of Slackware and I've always had a machine serving as my main server/firewall with the latest version installed.

I have it now but I'm struggling to find information on how to setup UPnP on it.

Can anyone please provide some good links where I can investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [linux-igd](http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net/).

> This project is a deamon that emulates
> Microsoft's Internet Connection
> Service (ICS). It implements the UPnP
> Internet Gateway Device specification
> (IGD) and allows UPnP aware clients,
> such as MSN Messenger to work properly
> from behind a NAT firewall.

This works fine with iptables...

Comment: And thanks also for adding the new tags. I don;t have enough rep yet :)